# create Pdf with a certain number of pages itext 7

Tags: itext7

How i can create Pdf with a certain number of pages.

I need to create a pdf with the exact number of pages, can I do that?

```
  public static void createPdf(int totalpages){ // totalpages количество страниц 
       PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
       Document document = new Document(pdf);
       pdf.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A5);
      

           document.add(new Paragraph("hello stackoverflow ... LONG TEXT"));
       
       document.close();
   }
```

Comment: one strategy would be to use a [PdfDocumentEvent](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/events/PdfDocumentEvent.html) with an [END_PAGE](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/events/PdfDocumentEvent.html#END_PAGE) so that when a new page is finished, you decide if you want to create a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not really sure about your scenario, but I suppose something like this could work?

```
private void limitPages() throws FileNotFoundException {
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
    EndPageHandler end = new EndPageHandler();
    pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, end);

    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    pdf.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A5);


    while (!end.done) {
        document.add(new Paragraph("hello stackoverflow ... LONG TEXT"));
    }
    document.close();
}

public class EndPageHandler implements IEventHandler {

    int pageCount = 0;
    int pageLimit = 5;
    boolean done = false;

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        //PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        pageCount++;
        if (pageCount == pageLimit) {
            done = true;
        }

    }
}
```

basically, after a page is done, it checks the page count. if it matches your criteria, it will exit the while look. Quick and dirty, but food for thought.